# How use nested map in node js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```js
let cc = "";
let allCourse = ['C#', 'C++', 'Java', 'Python'];

if (this.state.courses.length > 0) {
  allCourse.map(cr => {
    cc = this.state.courses.map((c, index) => {
      if (cr !== c) {
        return (
          <option value={cr} key={index} onClick={this.handleChange}>{cr}</option>
        )
      }
    })
  })
}
```

I want to print items except the ones in this.state.courses.
but
If this.state.courses is equal to 'java' The above code only prints Python

Comment: Explicitly `return` what you're storing in  `cc` : `return this.state.courses.map(/*...*/)`

Comment: you dont actually need nested loop. just use indexOf

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you want this:

```
let allCourse = ['C#', 'C++', 'Java', 'Python'];

if (this.state.courses.length > 0) {
    allCourse.map(cr => {
        return this.state.courses.indexOf(cr) === -1 && (
            <option value={cr} key={index} onClick={this.handleChange}>{cr}</option>
        )
    })
}
```